# Apex Test Parallel execution on Production

Tags: apex, unit-test

I know that we can [disable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_best_practices.htm) parallel Apex Test execution on Sandbox env

> You can prevent receiving those errors by turning off parallel test execution in the Salesforce user interface:
>
> - From Setup, enter Apex Test.
> - Click Options.... In the Apex Test Execution Options dialog,
> - select Disable Parallel Apex Testing and then click OK.

But how does this work in a **Production** environment?

- Is parallel execution enabled by default
- Can we disable it?

*While searching on SF stack I found this [Question](http://Can%20we%20use%20:%20Disable%20parallel%20apex%20testing%20option%20in%20production) (marked as duplicate) but the [duplicate one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72760/system-dmlexception-insert-failed-cannot-insert-update-activate-entity-at-produ) is removed*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referring [Testing Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_best_practices.htm) article.

Answers to your question- 'But how does this work in a Production environment?-:

1. Is parallel execution enabled by default

   - I think by default it is disabled.
2. Can we disable it?

   - `Apex Parallel Test Execution` can be disabled in Production as same way from setup menu as we do in any Sandbox.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you are absolutely correct. we can do the same changes in production in same  way while deploying the changes.